# What is the correct way to handle Stream filters in Reactor 2.0?

Tags: java, spring, reactor, project-reactor

I'm using Reactor 2.0.0.M1, and I'm trying to filter a `Stream`. Depending on the results of my boolean operation, I want to either continue with one or another stream. This seems to be possible with the `otherwise()` function, but its not exactly clear how to use it.

My Stream looks something like this:

```
stream.filter(o -> o.isValid());
```

To handle the case where `o.isValid()` is true, my understanding is I can just call `.map()` to continue down the stream.

To handle the case where `o.isValid()` is false, I can access the alternate `.otherwise()` stream.

But there doesn't seem to be an `or()` or similar method, so it doesn't seem possible to configure both streams in a completely fluid way.

The best I can come up with is something like this:

```
FilterAction<Object> filterAction = stream.filter(o -> o.isValid());

// Returns a 'true' Stream, which might additional operations
filterAction
    .map(o -> trueOperation1(o))
    .map(o -> trueOperation2(o));

// Returns a 'false' Stream, which might different additional operations
filterAction.otherwise()
    .map(o -> falseOperation1(o))
    .map(o -> falseOperation2(o));
```

Is that really the best way to proceed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved this by using groupBy() and flatMap().

Here is an example:

```
// your initial stream
Broadcaster<Object> stream = Streams.<Object>broadcast(environment);

stream
    .groupBy(o -> o.isValid())
    .flatMap(groupedStream -> {
        if (groupedStream.key()) {
            return groupedStream.map(o -> trueOperation(o));
        } else {
            return groupedStream.map(o -> falseOperation(o));
    }
    .map(o -> additionalOperations();
```

What happens here is that groupBy() converts your Stream into a `Stream<GroupedStream<O>>`. In other words, a stream of streams of objects. Each inner stream contains a group of objects that were bucketed by the operation in the groupBy() call. In my case, I've filtered the Objects into `true` and `false` buckets.

Next, flatMap() takes the multiple streams, processes them, and then flattens the output back into a single `Stream<Object>`. Within flatMap(), you can check the Stream's key(), and perform additional operations on the stream based on the key().

Then after the flatMap() finishes, you have a Stream again, and can do any post processing you want.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want

```
stream.filter(o -> {
  if (o.isValid()) {
    return trueOperation(o);
  } else {
    return falseOperation(o);
  }
});
```

Comment: That only make sense if the remainder of the stream is the same. What do you do when the stream behavior varies based on the filter result?